# limit rdp access for single users based on remote IP address

Tags: limit, ip-address, remote-desktop

I'm trying to limit the access of a single RD user to my Windows 2008 R2 Server based on IP address. The firewall Remote Desktop Inbound Rule (Tcp-In) works for all the users but it's not my case. Also I looked everywhere on the web but couldn't find a solution. I'm wondering if I can run a script after each login of the user, check the remote IP address and log him out if the IP address is not part of the authorized subnet. Is this a possible workaround?

Comment: The script solution will work but probably the user can switch to other IP and login? Why he can to RD from other IP but not from this one?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The user can connect only from a subnet, all the other IP addresses will lead him to be forcedly logged out.